# Why does my server not redirect me back to original page when blank using .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

Here is my code for .htaccess and the photo doesn't get the post.php? url params. I expected that when they visit the parameter-less site, mysite.com/gallery/photo/ to be redirected to mysite.com/gallery.

These are all tested with https://

```
RewriteEngine on

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

RewriteRule ^photo$ https://www.example.com/gallery/  [R=301,L]
```

AND trying this

```
RewriteRule ^photo$ https://www.example.com/gallery/  [NC,L]
```

I then try to shorten the testing to just the /gallery/photo/

It could take me 10 hours or trying every combination of .htaccess but I rather just know why my server will crash based on a quasi subset of parameters at the top. Is this because of a PHP or apache issue? Do people know how I can use a standardized set to redirect the user, and then finally use this subset?

I initially started using htaccess from a udemy course FYI

The resulting user should be

```
RewriteRule ^photo/([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)$ https://www.example.com/gallery/post.php?id=$1&url=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? And `photo` vs `photo/` are different things.

Comment: Also please specify clear examples for the different types of URLs you actually deal with. Currently we could only _guess_ which makes little sense if you want us to help.

Comment: the htaccess is located in multiple directories but the one I am referring to is in /gallery/.htacess
which should link /gallery/post.php?urlparms